# how to identify program creating large Visual Studio Extension files daily

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am having a space issue on my C drive.  I found that large (~300 [MB]) Visual Studio Extension (vsix) files are landing at C:\Windows\Temp daily (at exactly the same time), and sometimes multiple times per day.  I am not creating these.  I was able to delete the existing ones to buy me some time.  However, I want to identify the program / script that is creating these things, such that I can turn it off.  How can I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably Visual Studio tries to automatically update extensions:

[image]

And the program that actually download files is typically a scheduled task that you can try to locate in Windows Task Scheduler.